# Ada on STM32F4 (Cortex-M4)

Tags: ada, stm32, bare-metal, cortex-m

I just stumbled over this [article](http://www.embeddedrelated.com/showarticle/585.php) stating that there exists a port of the Ada language to Cortex-M4 micro-processors. This seems exciting but unfortunately I have found no such indication on [AdaCore](http://www.adacore.com).

Our target would be a STM32F407 or STMF417 bare-metal. Real-Time extensions of Ada are of paramount importance to us.

Preferably we would use the GPL version of the tools. However, being a University, we might get access to the respective university-version of the development suite.

**Can anybody share there experience with Ada on Cortex-M4 or even STM32, if any?**

I've eventually found the correct download including even a sample project for the STM32F4. Cool.

Comment: https://github.com/telrob/stm32-ada ?

Comment: [This article](http://electronicdesign.com/blog/running-ada-2012-cortex-m4) was linked from http://www.adacore.com/in-the-press on July 9,. Oh, and it's [official](http://www.adacore.com/press/gnat-gpl-for-bare-board-arm/)

Comment: You can find the download at http://libre.adacore.com; click through until you get to the download/configurations page and select the *ARM ELF format* platform (it’s available hosted on Linux or Windows).

Answer (score 5):

Green Hills sells an Ada 95 compiler for ARM (Cortex M4 boards are included)

Adacore also has the ability to handle Ada runtime libraries with gnat.

AdaCore Releases GNAT GPL for Bare Board ARM
  http://www.adacore.com/press/gnat-gpl-for-bare-board-arm/

I played around with the micro-kernel on github (link below).

https://github.com/Lucretia/tamp

It is relatively easy to work with and has great explanations on getting started, which seems to be your issue. I haven't done it in a while, but if you need help let me know I have an STM32F4 at home and I could get it up and running parallel to you and help you out if you get stuck.